# process.start("explorer"),the process will auto close

Tags: process

I want to make a program to open some directory and monitor when they are closed, but I had some trouble.
If `Process` opened `explorer.exe`, the process object will auto close right away, but 
`notepad.exe` will not.
 What should I do?

```
        string fileOpenPath = "F:\\testOpen";
        string fileHidePath = "F:\\test...\\";
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = fileOpenPath;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p.Exited += new EventHandler(Dir_Closed);
        if (!Directory.Exists(fileOpenPath))
        {
            Directory.Move(fileHidePath, fileOpenPath);
            p.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            p.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Explorer is a single-instance program. It's not clear what your goal is, but one solution is to use an ExplorerBrowser object, so that you have complete control over the window.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for your answer,and i think you already know my goal.I need keep the explorer's process infos in my program,and control this window,Mainly in the closure of the completion of some work.

Comment: If you are opening the folder because you expect the user to do some work in it, and you're using the closing of the folder as signaling that the work is complete: That is the exact scenario that ExplorerBrowser is for.